# Tutorial for Kinect 3D scanning over a wide area & export to LAS?

Tags: 3d, software-recommendations, las

I am interested in using a Kinect to 3D scan a large (~1 acre/0.4 hectare) area, but I am uncertain as to how I could best execute a surface scan of topography. Tutorials that I have seen online show the ability to scan individual rotating objects such as humans rotating on a stool/chair (see [Instructable here](http://www.instructables.com/id/EASY-Kinect-3D-Scanner/)). What would be the necessary steps/software when the surface remains still, but the Kinect moves? Would I simply set up the Kinect to record the 3D field as I walk around the site?

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I edited my question to focus on my main issue -- surface scanning and tying scans from a Kinect.

Comment: Your edit makes your question even broader.  For focused Q&A we need you to tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo Does this edit make the question sufficiently concise?

Comment: Others may vote to re-open but for me you still do not say what you have actually tried with your Kinect. It sounds like an idea that you have had but have not yet started to test for practicality.

Answer (score 2):

I would be very skeptical this could work because Kinect uses infrared, which will be disrupted by sunlight. It sounds like you want a terrestrial laser scanner.

It might be more helpful to describe what you are trying to accomplish before fixating on a specific tool (Kinect).

Comment: Excellent point, however the reason I am inquiring is because I would like to compare the Kenict results to a Terrestrial lidar scan of the same area. But, from your note, I am guessing that a better comparison would be between a TLS scan and some other method such as photogrammetry?